# My .php page is cut beneath textarea, scripts don't work as well

Tags: jquery, html, css

As I have written above, I wrote page in .php file, however, I have wrapped it in HTML (it is about to be a webpage project). The problem is that the scripts, nested in the  tag as follows:

```
      <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".r3").click(function(){
      $(".p3").show();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Don't work when I open them using Apache and, what's more, the webpage is cut beneath the textarea.

```
    <section class="wrapper-form">
  <form class="container" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="post.php">
    <h2 class="contact">Contact us</h2>
    <div class="formwrapper">
      <div class="inputs-column">
        <input class="input-general input-height" placeholder="name" type="text" name="name">
        <input class="input-general input-height" placeholder="e-mail" type="email" name="email">
        <input class="input-general input-height" placeholder="phone" type="text" name="phone">
      </div>
      <div class="inputs-column">
        <textarea class="input-general textarea1" placeholder="Your message..." type="text" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-align">
      <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="send message">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

And therefore the elements it contains are not visible. Instead the place beneath textarea is perceived by the browser as the end of the page. I enclose also the beginning of the code if it would be helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the whole thing is ended with `</html>` tag.

Comment: Where are your PHP tags? <?php and ?>

Comment: The classes that your jquery mentions dont appear to be in the html posted above so it wont work. also you stated this is a php page, but there are no php tags anywhere here.

Comment: Can you upload the full code to pastebin or some similar service and share that with us?

Comment: Note, it's worth using the preview feature before posting a question on Stack Overflow. Bare HTML tags like `</html>` need to be enclosed in backticks to be visible in the text.